# How to prevent partial labels from appearing in QGIS Layout Manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

How do I prevent labels from partially appearing on the QGIS print layout?

[image]

I have tried to editing the label properties and have unchecked the "Allow truncated labels on edges of map" checkbox but still this does not prevent partial labels from displaying the layout manager.

[image]

Any suggestions? I am using 3.16.4-Hannover.

I have also unchecked the "Allow truncated labels on edges of map"

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Element properties` go to the tab `Label settings` and deactivate the checkbox `Allow truncated labels on edges of map` (see screenshots below).

If that doesn't help, check if you have activated `Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)` in the QGIS main windows under label settings / [Rendering tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html?highlight=label#rendering-tab).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Babel but unfortunately this does not work. This box was already unchecked. I'll add a screenshot of this to main query

Comment: Have you activated `Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)` in the QGIS main windows under label settings / Rendering tab? De-activate it and refresh the print composer window.

Comment: Yes I had this setting activated. i have deactivated it and it is now working. Thank you